# setInterval и clearInterval

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';


var time = 0;
var sec = 0;
var min = 0;
var hour = 0;
var timer = 0;
var timeSec = document.getElementById('sec');
var timeMin = document.getElementById('min');
var timeHour = document.getElementById('hour');
var pos = 0;

function start() {
 var timeStart = Math.round((new Date()).getTime()/1000);
 var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  var timeNow = Math.round((new Date()).getTime()/1000);
  time = timeNow - timeStart;
  sec = time % 60;
  min = ((time - time % 60) / 60) % 60;
  hour = ((time - time % 3600) / 3600 );
  // console.log(sec+" "+min+" "+hour);
  if (sec < 10) {
   timeSec.innerHTML = "0"+sec;
  } else {
   timeSec.innerHTML = sec;
  };
  if (min < 10) {
   timeMin.innerHTML = "0"+min;
  }else {
  timeMin.innerHTML = min;
  }
  if(hour < 10) {
   timeHour.innerHTML = "0"+hour;
  } else {
   timeHour.innerHTML = hour;
  }
 } , 1000);
}

function reset() {
 clearInterval(timerId);
 time = 0;
 sec = "--";
 timeSec.innerHTML = sec;
 timeMin.innerHTML = sec;
 timeHour.innerHTML = sec;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Секундомер</div>
  <div class="watch">
   <h1><b id="output"><span id="hour">--</span>:<span id="min">--</span>:<span id="sec">--</span></b></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
   <button onclick="start()">Start/Stop</button>
   <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
 </div>
```

не пойму в чем проблема, почему timerId undefined?

Comment: Потому что timerId объявлен внутри функции start и существует только внутри неё

Comment: Что то я похоже туплю, var же делает переменную глобальным нет?

Comment: Всё ровно наоборот, var создаёт локальную переменную в том месте, где она объявлена

Comment: Чтож спасибо. Те никак нельзя объявить переменную в функции чтобы ее было видно из вне?

Comment: Никак. Но зачем, если можно создать переменную в глобальной области видимости? По аналогии с вашими var time, var sec и так далее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынеси объявление `timerId`, потому что данная переменная является локальной в контексте функции `start()` и не всплывает в глобальную область видимости.

### Решение:

```js
'use strict';


var time = 0;
var sec = 0;
var min = 0;
var hour = 0;
var timer = 0;
var timeSec = document.getElementById('sec');
var timeMin = document.getElementById('min');
var timeHour = document.getElementById('hour');
var pos = 0;
var timerId;

function start() {
  var timeStart = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
  timerId = setInterval(function() {
    var timeNow = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    time = timeNow - timeStart;
    sec = time % 60;
    min = ((time - time % 60) / 60) % 60;
    hour = ((time - time % 3600) / 3600);
    // console.log(sec+" "+min+" "+hour);
    if (sec < 10) {
      timeSec.innerHTML = "0" + sec;
    } else {
      timeSec.innerHTML = sec;
    };
    if (min < 10) {
      timeMin.innerHTML = "0" + min;
    } else {
      timeMin.innerHTML = min;
    }
    if (hour < 10) {
      timeHour.innerHTML = "0" + hour;
    } else {
      timeHour.innerHTML = hour;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function reset() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  time = 0;
  sec = "--";
  timeSec.innerHTML = sec;
  timeMin.innerHTML = sec;
  timeHour.innerHTML = sec;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Секундомер</div>
  <div class="watch">
    <h1><b id="output"><span id="hour">--</span>:<span id="min">--</span>:<span id="sec">--</span></b></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button onclick="start()">Start/Stop</button>
    <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: так как раз при 'use strict' var timerId  не делает переменную глобальным?

Comment: @TigranVardanyan дело даже не в use strict, timerId просто локальная переменная внутри функции start(), не имеющая объявления вне функции.

Comment: Да тут я не правильно понял теорию. То есть в функции никак нельзя объявить переменную которая была бы видна из наружи?

Comment: @TigranVardanyan прочитай, думаю поможет https://getinstance.info/articles/javascript/variables-scope-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо вывести `var timerId` за пределами функции `start()`

```js
'use strict';


var time = 0;
var sec = 0;
var min = 0;
var hour = 0;
var timer = 0;
var timeSec = document.getElementById('sec');
var timeMin = document.getElementById('min');
var timeHour = document.getElementById('hour');
var pos = 0;
var timerId = '';

function start() {
 var timeStart = Math.round((new Date()).getTime()/1000);
 timerId = setInterval(function() {
  var timeNow = Math.round((new Date()).getTime()/1000);
  time = timeNow - timeStart;
  sec = time % 60;
  min = ((time - time % 60) / 60) % 60;
  hour = ((time - time % 3600) / 3600 );
  // console.log(sec+" "+min+" "+hour);
  if (sec < 10) {
   timeSec.innerHTML = "0"+sec;
  } else {
   timeSec.innerHTML = sec;
  };
  if (min < 10) {
   timeMin.innerHTML = "0"+min;
  }else {
  timeMin.innerHTML = min;
  }
  if(hour < 10) {
   timeHour.innerHTML = "0"+hour;
  } else {
   timeHour.innerHTML = hour;
  }
 } , 1000);
}

function reset() {
 clearInterval(timerId);
 time = 0;
 sec = "--";
 timeSec.innerHTML = sec;
 timeMin.innerHTML = sec;
 timeHour.innerHTML = sec;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Секундомер</div>
  <div class="watch">
   <h1><b id="output"><span id="hour">--</span>:<span id="min">--</span>:<span id="sec">--</span></b></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
   <button onclick="start()">Start/Stop</button>
   <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
 </div>
```